# AMD OpenCL fatal error: CL/cl.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencl, amd-app

I'm trying to compile a simple "hello world" program on Windows 7 using OpenCL in Visual Studio 2015 in C++. Upon trying to build, I get this error:

```
Cannot open include file: 'CL/cl.hpp': No such file or directory
```

I have looked for various solutions, and they all say

> make sure the path is correct.

My path points to the right place (`AMDAPPSDKROOT` pointing to `C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\2.9-1\`), inside which there is an `include` folder, and inside that there is the `CL` folder containing all the libraries, including `cl.hpp`.

In the project properties, I have set `Additional Include Directories` to include `$(AMDAPPSDKROOT)\include`, which I believe points it at `C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\2.9-1\include`. I have also set `Additional Library Directories` to point to `$(AMDAPPSDKROOT)\lib\x86`.

So why can't Visual Studio find it? I really don't understand the cause of this problem. Is it something to do with the architecture (I'm using x86)?

Comment: Is `AMDAPPSDKROOT` an environment variable? Did you recently add that. If so did you reboot and try again?

Comment: Inside of `C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\2.9-1\include` is there a CL folder?

Comment: AMDAPPSDKROOT is an environment variable, I assume it got set when I installed the SDK from [here](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/), it is a system variable though, not a user variable. I just rebooted and am having the same problem. There is a CL (and GL) folder inside of C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\2.9-1\include.

Comment: Oddly though, if I set the Additional Include Directories straight to the file location (i.e. to C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\2.9-1\include instead of $(AMDAPPSDKROOT)\include), it finds the files. I suppose there must be something wrong with the default configuration somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a "solution" but if instead of using the AMDAPPSDKROOT variable I just point the project's "Additional Include Directories" straight to the file location, it can find them. I don't know why it wouldn't work using the environment variable though, since it points to exactly the same place.